# calculate the limit of the function $f(ax)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has limit $L$ at $0$, and let $a > 0$. If $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  is defined by
$g(x):= f(ax)$ for $x \in R$, show that $\lim\limits_{x\to o} {g(x)}=L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta_1$ such that for $|x| \lt \delta_1$ we have $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$
Take $\delta = \frac{\delta_1}{a}$ then if $|x| \lt \delta$ then $|ax| \lt \delta_1 \implies |f(ax)-L| \lt \epsilon \implies |g(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Well clearly as $x \to 0 , ax \to 0, $ and $  g(x) \to 0 $, so it follows from your definition because we would have f(0)=L